# “Validation failed” error on searching in private repository with installation of GitHub App

Tags: github-api-v3, octokit.net, github-app

I’ve created a GitHub app and installed it in my account, giving it access to a private repository in my account. The GitHub app has read permission to metadata.
I then generated a JWT and used it to create an installation access token, following the steps here.
I tried using this token to search for keywords in the above private repository using the GitHub search API as follows:

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=abc+in:file+repo:username/private-repo
```

However, this returns the following response.

```
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.",
            "resource": "Search",
            "field": "q",
            "code": "invalid"
        }
    ],
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/v3/search/"
}
```

I tried using this access token to fetch the repositories for this GitHub app installation and that returned the private repo successfully in the response. I assume this means that the installation has access to the private repo and the token works as expected.
API used: `https://api.github.com/installation/repositories`.

Why does the search fail then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raised a ticket with GitHub support. Their response:

> The query failed because the GitHub App does not have permission to
> `read` the content of the private repository. The Metadata `read`
> permission will allow you to search for repositories but does not have
> sufficient scope to `read` the content of the repository(private).

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/permissions-required-for-github-apps) list the search API under Metadata, but it should be under Content permissions. Granting Content `read` permissions to the GitHub app solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the value of the "q" field. When I dropped the `+repo` argument I was able to search code just fine. I'm still not sure why the `+repo` did not work (it worked fine on the command line) but it turns out I didn't need it anyways since the repos were constrained to where the app was installed and I could also filter the results if needed.

Comment: I had the same problem when I included the repo, but when I chose to *NOT* URL encode the query string, the repo param started working.

This worked for me:

`https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=hash:THE_FULL_HASH+repo:ORG-NAME/REPO-NAME`

Even though I specify hash, I included the repo because I assume GH might search faster if I include it.
Notes: [1] I had no GH App involved. Was just searching a repo directly.
[2] I didn't try with a 7 character hash. Maybe that works, too.
[3] I was using a GitHub PAT with perms to read the repo